# Redirection after Form Submission

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

In Silverstripe < 3 you can do smth like this in a form action

```
Director::redirect(Director::baseURL(). $this->URLSegment . "/?success=1");
```

and then in Template you can check with <% if Success %> if the Form is submitted.

in >3.1 you'll get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Director::redirect()
```

somehow one shold use SS_HTTPRequest but i do not get it how to use this guy.

I want to show a simple success message after form submission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are handling the form submission in a `Controller` to redirect you could use

`$this->redirect( Director::baseURL() . $this->URLSegment . "/?success=1" );`

Comment: thank you colymba - this is the first part for me. all this director stuff is still a mistery to me. is it save to put smth like this in the controller to make a decision in template with a <% if  success %> ?

 public function success() {
  return ($this->getRequest()->getVar("success")) ? true : false;
 }

Comment: I don't see why it would not be safe, so sure. Although even without submitting the form and changing the URL this would still return true, so you might want to do some double checking...

Comment: well it just returns true if success has a parameter, so it does not return true in each case. for double checking - it returns false if ./?success=0 - or what do you mean?

Comment: if someone visits YOURURL/?success=1 they can fake form submission once they have seen how it works...

Comment: yes i know - but in this case it does not hurt. anyway how would you do? also write smth to a session or what wold be the "good" way to do it?

Comment: I've done something like that with a session variable once. Set it when the form is submitted. And in the success function check if it exists and if so, return true and clear the session. But like you said, it doesn't always matter...